# iOS Firebase push notifications not working on iPhone 11 in production

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios

The react-native app I'm working on has been having this issue for quite a while, background notifications are not working in the production app. This only happens for the iPhone 11 as we've tested with the iPhone 8 (both devices were running iOS 13.3) in production and it received them, so I don't think it would have to do with production's APNs certs. We've upgraded to .61 as well as react-native-firebase 6 hoping that that might solve the issue but to no avail, tried adding APNs headers to the message as well as some other things but nothing seems to be working. Like I said this is only happening in production, we've tried with the 11 in dev and QA and both times we were able to receive notifications.

Is there something specific that is required for iPhone 11s when using Firebase Messaging? Is there any way to view real time logs in Firebase (ie the images of logs in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023623/react-native-firebase-push-notifications-not-firing-production-fcm-cloud-functi)), all I've been able to find in the Firebase console is aggregated data for the app. I would like to be able to send a test notification to a specific user on prod from Insomnia and see if it is failing, why it's failing etc.

Any help would be appreciated if any other info is needed please let me know. Thanks.